# Inserting Single/double type to DB using VBA in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, locale

I need some help with an issue that is doing my head in.
I need to update a database in access and its been working fine operating with Long and Integers.

Look at this code.

```
sql = "UPDATE DBNAME SET Long_Field = " & Long_Variable & " WHERE ID = " & id
DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```

This code runs flawlessly, it takes a long variable and puts it into the correct field which is set as Long.

However, if I want to populate a single/double field (ive tried both)

```
sql = "UPDATE DBNAME SET Double_Field = " & double_Variable & " WHERE ID= " & id
DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```

I keep getting Run-Time error 3144: Syntax error in update statement.
I can literally just switch out the field name and the variable name and the code runs flawlessly, but as soon as i try to send a double value, for example (5,8), to a field in the table that is set to double, it gives me this error.

Anyone?

Comment: When you say a _double_  value are you talking about two values e.g (5 and 8) or is the comma the decimal separator?

Comment: comma is the decimal

Comment: Ah, ok.... was just checking the obvious. :)

Comment: try cdbl(double_variable)

Comment: If i for example set double_variable = 5, and send it. it works fine. but if i set it to = 5.8, it bugs out. even tho the table is set to recieve double, doesnt matter if decimals is set to auto or 1

Comment: try debug.? typename(double_variable) also

Comment: @J.Chomel: please don't reject edits that change a wrong tag into the correct one. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/access/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want a dot as decimal separator in your string.

The conversion from double to string is done using the separator from the system locale settings so in your case a comma.

This means that

```
double_variable = 5.8
sql = "... " & double_variable & " ..."
```

will produce `... 5,8 ...` in the sql variable.
The easiest way to fix that is to use

```
"..." & Replace(CStr(double_variable), ",", ".") & "..."
```

This will replace all `,` with `.`. I put the `CStr` there to make sure it gets converted to a string first. It will also work if the system locale changes since nothing will happen if there is no `,`. The only caveat is that if for some reason the conversion inserts 1000s separators it will fail but that would only be relevant in other circumstances as I don't think `CStr` will ever do that.

Comment: Even if i define a variable named double_variable As Double, set it to double_variable = 5.8,  and then send it, it still throws the error. If i however set it to double_variable = 5, it works fine.

Comment: You need the full expression (Replace , -> .) @Arne

Comment: @Arne did you try my suggestion? I added a little more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The current answer is not the easiest, neither the simplest.

The universal method is to use *Str* as it always returns a dot as the decimal separator:

```
sql = "UPDATE DBNAME SET Double_Field = " & Str(double_Variable) & " WHERE ID = " & id & ""
```

Comment: Wow. I was totally not aware of this. Thanks!